# C# Wpf How to Add DoubleClick Function to "WPF NotifyIcon"

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I try to use WPF NotifyIcon from here : [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon)

I created a taskbarIcon like this.

```
        TaskbarIcon tbi = new TaskbarIcon();
        tbi.DoubleClickCommand =
```

I want to add a function to DoubleClickCommand. It seems like it needs a ICommand.
How can i do this in code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This is command defining 
private ICommand myCommand; 

public ICommand MyCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (myCommand== null)
         myCommand= new RelayCommand(MyMethod);
      return myCommand;
   }
   set { myCommand= value; }
}


  //This is your command method
  public void MyMethod()
  {
  }

  //This is your xaml
  <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

**If you need parameter for pass to method;**

```
myCommand= new RelayCommand<object>(MyMethod);//Change here like this;
```

**And Change the XAML like this**

```
//You can pass string parameter
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="MyParameter"/>        
Or
//You can pass a property
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own commands as [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) and then assign as

```
tbi.DoubleClickCommand = YourCreatedCommand;
```

You can also refer to : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059914/wpf-binding-to-commands-in-code-behind) for more information